# How would I filter the results from Tesseract against a dictionary supplied?

Tags: python, tesseract

I started learning Python a bit ago and just now have started learning Tesseract to create a tool for my own use. I have a script written to take four screenshots of specific parts of the screen and then it uses Tesseract to pull data from those images. It is mostly accurate, and gets the words almost 100% of the time, but there is still some garbage letters and symbols that I don't want in the results.

Rather than trying to process the image (if this really is the easiest way, I could do it, but I still feel like that would result in more data coming through that I don't want) I would like to only keep the words in the result that are in the dictionary I can provide.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(580,430,780,500))
im.save(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab.png')

im2=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(770,430,960,500))
im2.save(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab2.png')

im3=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(950,430,1150,500))
im3.save(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab3.png')

im4=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1140,430,1320,500))
im4.save(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab4.png')

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab.png')
image2 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab2.png')
image3 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab3.png')
image4 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab4.png')

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab.png'))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab2.png'))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab3.png'))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\tesseract_images\imagegrab4.png'))
```

This is what I've written above. It might not be as clean as possible but it does what I want it to for now. When I run the program against the test screenshot I've taken, I get the following:

```
Ballistica Prime Receiver

a

   

  

“Ze ij
Titania Prime Blueprint

—

 

‘|! stradavar Prime
Blueprint

My.

 

Bronco Prime Barrel

uby-
```

Here is my screenshot:[image]

It can pick up the words perfectly fine, but the data like "uby-" and "‘|! " aren't needed and is why I want to hopefully clean them out by only keeping words that are in the dictionary. If there's an easier way to do this I'd love to know as I haven't been using Tesseract but for a day or so and don't know of another way I'd do it other than the aforementioned image processing.

Comment: can you please add a picture of your test screenshot

Comment: @TERMINATOR edited the post to include it

Comment: I see since you have low rep I helped to add the picture